C Can I use data that I freed just after freeing it
I have a linked list node I want to code a function that frees node.
But order to do that I have to update next variable of previous node.
Can I access to previous_node->next (previous_node->next->next) just after freeing it?
struct node
{
   struct node *next;
}

void free_node(struct node *previous_node)
{
   free(previous_node->next);

   previous_node->next = previous_node->next->next; // can i do it or i have to store previous_node->next->next in a variable before freeing previous_node->next
}

I assembled it to see if there will be any diffrence but I saw my compiler to optimize it to how i write at up.

You can try, but the behaviour is undefined. Sod's Law says it might work today, but not when you make your presentation. You should make a temporary pointer before freeing. struct node *temp = previous_node->next->next; free(previous_node->next); previous_node->next = temp;

There is nothing to stop an implementation of free() from modifying the released data.  After all, you just said you don't want to access it again by freeing it.  Most implementations don't modify the released space, but you should not rely on it.


Can I use data that I freed just after freeing it

No, that would exhibit undefined behavior.

or i have to store previous_node->next->next in a variable before freeing previous_node->next

Yes.
